# QDockWidget ignores layouts and size policy from the form

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt6

I'm subclassing from QDockWidget and I want my class to use form. I've made a form based on QWidget and included Ui class in my QDockWidget-based class. But the build result differs from the Qt Designer preview, because QDockWidget completely ignores all the preset size policies and layouts from the form, so most of the content just doesn't show up and the rest has nothing in common with the preset settings. My class looks fine if I subclass from QMainWindow or QWidget. How to use forms for QDockWidget?

Answer (score 0):

This question could do with some sample code from the .ui files to clarify the question.

However one possible cause of this is that Qt form layouts QFormLayout by default don't expand to fill their parent widget. If the QFormLayout is embedded another top level layout such as a grid layout the contents of the QFormLayout will then expand to fill the available space.